# VSCode "unresolved import" error for subfolders

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a project with the following folder layout:

```
app/ #actual python aplication code
|-- package1/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- Class1.py
|-- package2/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- Class2.py
|-- app.py # application entrypoint
venv/ #virtenv generated from python3
Dockerfile #release dockerfile
```

Everything works fine from the image generated via `Dockerfile` running `python app.py` and I can execute and debug the application from inside VSCode simply by right-clicking on `app.py` and choosing the appropriate command.
Buuuut,VSCode is showing a warning message about `unresolved import` as `app.py`. The relevant `app.py` code snippet is as follows

```
import package1
import package2
```

Nothing breaks, everything runs fine. It just seems to me that VSCode doesn't understand that `app.py` is not at the root folder, so the python interpreter should not try to import from the root folder. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Comment: Who is saying there is an unresolved import? Pylint?

Comment: The Python extension installed in VSCode

Answer (score 1):

The issue is whatever tool is warning you about your imports doesn't know that `app` is the anchor point for your code and not `../app` as you opened as your workspace. You will need to either open `app` as your workspace or tell the extension that `app/` is where Python should start looking (typically via `PYTHONPATH` in a `.env` file).